Is it possible to vectorize scipy multivariate_normal over means?
I have a multivariate normal distribution. I use it in a markov chain sampler, that makes use of vectorization option. That means that it is most optimal, when it can request logarithm of PDF for multiple different mean vectors at the same time. Below is a minimal example. The first piece of code makes a request for a single datapoint an a single mean vector, it works fine. The second piece of code makes a request for multiple mean vectors. For the second piece of code, I get the error
ValueError: Array 'mean' must be a vector of length 600.

Is there a built-in way around this, or do I have to use a for-loop?
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

np.random.seed(42)
cov = np.diag(np.ones(6))


mu = np.random.normal(0, 1, 6)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 6)
print(multivariate_normal.logpdf(x, mean=mu, cov=cov))

mu = np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 6))
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 6))
print(multivariate_normal.logpdf(x, mean=mu, cov=cov))

EDIT: I just found a solution for a single datapoint. Since mean and data are interchangeable for normal distribution, the following would yield the correct result
mu = np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 6))
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 6)
print(multivariate_normal.logpdf(mu, mean=x, cov=cov))


scipy.stats does not offer this, but you might be able to use the JAX implementation, which supports vectorisation. JAX is duck typed, so you can use it as input to code that expects python arrays, with some restrictions (JAX does not have in-place modification, for example).
Here is a minimal example:
import jax
import jax.random as jr
from jax.scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

key = jr.key(0)
samples = jr.multivariate_normal(key, jnp.zeros(3), jnp.eye(3), shape=(1000,))

get_logpdfs = jax.vmap(multivariate_normal.logpdf, in_axes=(0, None, None))
logpdfs = get_logpdfs(samples, jnp.zeros(3), jnp.eye(3))

print(samples.shape, logpdfs.shape)

